# SSRS does not display data when deployed

Tags: reporting-services

[image: Report dispaly]

This is the display after I uploaded the report. Only the headers are showing up. Everything worked locally

Comment: Check the dataset is correct on the server, datasets are not overwritten by default so if you have a dataset on the server with the same name it might be using that one instead,

Comment: Solved it. Thanks man.